# pandas plot distinct values of a column after groupby on another column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to plot 2 line charts on the graph, with x-axis being month and y-axis being the count for each city for each month.

I do a group by on the month to get the count for each city.

my df:

```
city month 
A      1
A      2
A      2
B      2
B      3
C      3

df['city'].groupby(df['month']).size().plot()
```

I want to see 2 line charts, 1 for A and 1 for B for each of the month on the x-axis.

The code above only gives me the accumulation for each month, but i want a **breakdown for each city**.

[image]

How can i have 2 line charts for the distinct values of the city column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need `groupby` with `size` for count and reshape by `unstack`, last filter columns (cities) by `subset`:

```
df.groupby(['month', 'city']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)[['A','B']].plot()
```

Similar:

```
pd.crosstab(df['month'], df['city'])[['A','B']].plot()
```

For plot all cities is possible omit subset `[[]]`.

If want filter top counts:

```
top = df['city'].value_counts().head(2).index
df.query('city in @top').groupby(['month', 'city']).size().unstack(fill_value=0).plot()
```

Comment: i have over 50 values in my city list. how can i not manually print each one out as in your code `['A','B']`

Comment: @jxn - You can omit `[['A','B']]` but `50` lines should be not very nice.

Comment: @jxn - In my opinion some 5, maybe 10 cities should be enough.

Comment: is there a way to say keep the top 5?

Comment: Do you think top counts? `df['city'].value_counts().head(2).index` ?

Comment: @jxn - you are welcome! also was added solution for filter before.